# Difference between `npm i` and `npm i <package name>`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install

In my React Native project, I have a given version of `react` in my `package.json`, but if I run `npm i react`, it will install the latest version of `react`. If I run `npm i` though, will it install all the packages in my `package.json`, with the versions given in the `package.json`? I don't want it to install the latest versions of all the packages, so I'm scared to try it without asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should go through documentation before getting into anything :)

Using `npm i` will install whatever is stated in the `package.json`. If the `package.json` binds the packages to versions, then it will install that specific version. Most often, `package.json` would use the `^` character before the package version, which stands for *any version above the mentioned version*, and if that is the case for you, yes, `npm i` will install the latest version of those packages.